# type casting works differently for long to int and int to short in java

Tags: java, math, casting

1. ```
   short t=(short)1 * 3 ;
   ```
2. ```
   int tadpole = (int)5 * 2L ;
   ```

First statement works perfectly fine, But second throws compilation error.
According to the rules, when performing arithmetic operations, if any byte/short/char will be converted to int by default. So how is first expression working?

also, I checked for

3. ```
   short x = (int) 30;
   ```
4. ```
   int y = (long) 30;
   ```

statement 3 works, but statement 4 doesn't work.

Why can I assign an `int` to a `short`, but not `long` to `int`?

Comment: Your arguments are being promoted to `int` when using `+`/`*`/etc per JLS [§15.17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17): `Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands` ([§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)). The first line will compile with literals, but if that `1` was replaced with a `short` variable you'd need to cast the entire expression.

Comment: Can you please tell interms of expressions 3,4.

Comment: The first one works because 1*3 is 3 which is within the range of short.  You don't need to the cast.  It doesn't do anything.

Comment: 5*2= 10 is also within the raange of int, then why is second expression not working?

Comment: `2L` is a `long`, which means the other operand is promoted to `long`. The first expression can be evaluated at compile-time and is confirmed to be within bounds, so it will not throw an error. If you did `short t = (short) ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt() * (short) 3;` or even `short s = (short) 99999 * (short) 3;` it would not compile. #3 works as `int` can be assigned to `short` for compile-time constants. #4 doesn't work because `long` cannot be assigned to `int`, even with compile-time constants.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in section [5.2 Assignment Conversion of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Your examples 1 and 3 fall under this clause: these are constant expressions (with a value of 3 or 30), the type of the expression is `int` and the values fit into a `short`.

There is no similar clause for constant expressions with `long` values.

Your examples 2 and 4 produce `long` values (in example 2 because one of the operands is `long`, in example 4 because of the cast to `long`).

---

Please note that your examples 1 and 2 are probably not interpreted as you might think they are. Casting has higher precedence than multiplication and therefore the examples are evaluated as if they were written as:

1. ```
   short t = ((short)1) * 3 ;
   ```
2. ```
   int tadpole = ((int)5) * 2L ;
   ```

---

**Why does this rule exist?**

One of the reasons is the definition of [Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1): any time the source code contains an integer number (without the suffix `l` or `L` which would make it a `long`) the type of that literal is `int`.

The rule from "Assignment Conversion" means that you can write

```
byte[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Without that rule, you would have to write

```
byte[] data = { (byte) 1, (byte) 2, (byte) 3, (byte) 4 };
```

There is no need for a similar rule for `long` constants.

Comment: TLDR; It is because it is how Java is written!